# How to Normalize the ideal Tx and Equalized Waveforms in LMS algorithm

Tags: normalization

[image]Below mentioned steps has been done but I don't know if I am doing the right way of Normalizing the 2 signals.
Ref_1 = load('Tx_16QAM_25_New.txt'); % transmitted data
Tx(:,1)=Ref_1(:,1)+1i*Ref_1(:,2);
Tx = Tx(:,1);
Tx1=rms(Tx)
normTx=Tx./Tx1

Eq=c'*X;   % received symbol estimation
Eq1=rms(Eq)
NormEq=Eq./Eq1

Normalized Tx,Rx plots are attched while no plot is obtained for the normalized equalized constellation.
Rx1 =3.1859, Eq1=Inf, Tx1=3.16 (RMS Values)

Comment: Umar- This looks correct, and for the Rx assuming it is the converged symbols. Can you show a plot of your first 100 or so Tx symbols and then put the result you got for the rms value?

Comment: https://ibb.co/DCBy32H ;   https://ibb.co/QbZdVxT ;   Plot for ideal Tx and plot for ideal Tx and received distorted combined.

Comment: "and then put the result you got for the rms value?"  Sorry I don't understand this.

Comment: Hi you just gave waveforms, you want to extract the symbols at the decision points and put them on a complex I Q constellation. If it is 16QAM you will see 16 dots for Tx and 16 clouds close to those areas for Rx if you have low EVM. What you should do is create those constellations and put them specifically in your question above so all can see clearly and the work you have done. And then also compute what you think the RMS value is and put that right in your question. You may answer your own question by going through that exercise but this will also make your question as presented better.

Comment: - In consideration and to the benefit of future viewers-- a well written question is one where the readers won't have to read all these comments to figure out what exactly you are asking so that would help a lot if you could do that :)